# Android Viewgroup add circles onTouch

Tags: android, viewgroup, ontouch

I have a viewgroup class with several views added to it. On top of all these views I want to add a small circle wherever I receive a touch on the screen.  When fingers are removed from the screen so should these circles indicating where the touches were. I know how I'd do this in a class extending View but how can it be done in a viewgroup without affecting any of the other views on the screen?

Comment: instead of onDraw use dispatchDraw and instead  of onTouchEvent use dispatchTouchEvent

Comment: Add in your ViewGroup constructor `setWillNotDraw(false)` to get calls in `onDraw()`, and do the drawing it as you would do it in `View`